How do I set up Sveltekit routing for production. Using adapter node
I can't figure out how to set up my built sveltekit app, (used node adapter) to route requests.
During development, to get my frontend to communicate with my backend I have my http request with axios and then my vite config set up with the proper proxies.
I built my project with node adapter, and I really can't figure out how to set up the routing for production. It works in development fine, I've been really stuck on this one and can't find any reference to it in docs or anywhere. I'm not using nginx or anything, my stack is as follows:
Frontend - Sveltekit (axios for requests, node adapter during build)
Backend - Node/Express and an SQL server
Kept it minimal so I'm not overwhelmed.
Any help is appreciated.
I am really clueless at this point and don't know where to start. So close to finishing.

Did you read the Node adapter docs explaining its use with a custom server?

I did read them, the docs are where I went first. Reading over the link you sent. Will update accordingly. I read over this section. I was heading in the right direction but didn't get it to work. From my understanding its going from Svelte => adapter node server => external backend server + database? and those are like a proxy that are hit when my frontend makes a http request? kind of how i set up proxies in vite?

SvelteKit generates a middleware you can register in your server, it's not a proxy.

i cant believe i did that. i was so tired, i feel like it was such an easy thing to overlook.
steps to solve:
copied the code for custom server in the link,
configured axios,
configured cors,
fixed ssl cert,
and it worked.
thanks brunnerh. one day I wont be a scrub.
